# Using conditional operator with mixed data types in String.Format

Tags: c#, wpf, string.format

I have a String.Format method that I want to insert either a string or an int, depending on whether a condition is met. My code looks like this:

```
Box.Text = String.Format("{0}", ScoreBoolCheck ? student1.ScoreInt : "null");
```

So ideally, the method should check whether ScoreBoolCheck is true, and if so, insert student1.ScoreInt, but if not, it should insert the string "null" instead.

However, this doesn't work yet. I am getting an alert that says "there is no implicit conversion between int and string." Anyone see where I'm going wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast to `object`:

```
Box.Text = String.Format("{0}", ScoreBoolCheck ? (object)student1.ScoreInt : "null");
```

As there is an implicit conversion from `string` to `object`, this will work just fine. Assuming `ScoreInt`is an `int`, it will get boxed, but it would have been boxed anyway while passing parameters to `String.Format` (its last parameter is of type `object[]`).

The conversion is required, as the ternary expression *must* have a type.

You can't write:

```
var x = someCondition ? 42 : Guid.NewGuid();
```

Because no type could be assigned to `x`, as `int` and `Guid` aren't compatible (none of these can be assigned to the other one).

But if you write:

```
var x = someCondition ? (object)42 : Guid.NewGuid();
```

Then `x` is unambiguously of type `object`. `Guid` can be implicitly boxed to `object`.

Comment: Thanks! Both your's and Shaharyar's approach work. Is there a reason to prefer casting as an object over calling ToString()? Also, why does there need to be any conversion here in the first place?

Comment: Both approaches are perfectly fine for your case, so you can freely choose the one you prefer. In the general case, mine works with types other than `string`: `someCondition ? (object)42 : Guid.NewGuid()` for instance. There needs to be a conversion because the ternary expression itself must have a type. If you have something like `var x = someCondition ? 42 : Guid.NewGuid();` what would be the type of `x`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `int` to `string`:

```
String.Format("{0}", ScoreBoolCheck ? student1.ScoreInt.ToString() : "null");
```